# Neo4J Cypher - Union & With Clause usage

Tags: neo4j, union, cypher, with-statement

I'm trying to create a invoice product subgraph using UNION in my query and then would like to pass only the invoice nodes using WITH to a subquery. It looks like below

```
MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product)
WHERE year.value='2014' and day.value IN ['27','28','29','30','31'] and month.value='January'
RETURN (inv:Invoice)-[:PRODUCT]->(prd:Product)
UNION
MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product)
WHERE year.value='2014' and day.value IN ['01','02','03','04'] and month.value='February'
WITH inv
MATCH (inv)-[p:PROCESSED_AT]-(time:Time) WHERE p.time > 700 and p.time < 900
RETURN inv.invid
```

But I'm getting this error - All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names. Any inputs on where im going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is really clear that the 2 parts of your UNION is not returning the same number of columns to make a union.  if I understand correctly you are trying to get all the invoices for a particular product which has a invalid timestamp. I don't think if that is the case you will need a UNION instead you may need a WITH clause.

Anyways, to fix the above query you may want to just match the 2 parts of the UNION as below

```
MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product)
WHERE year.value='2014' and day.value IN ['27','28','29','30','31'] and month.value='January'
MATCH (inv:Invoice)-[:PRODUCT]->(prd:Product)
RETURN inv, prd
UNION
MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product)
WHERE year.value='2014' and day.value IN ['01','02','03','04'] and month.value='February'
WITH inv
MATCH (prd:Product)<-[:PRODUCT]-(inv)-[p:PROCESSED_AT]-(time:Time) WHERE p.time > 700 and p.time < 900
RETURN inv, prd
```

.

**EDIT**

I think you have got `UNION` , `RETURN` and `WITH` a bit off, to be honest I don't know how we can use UNION to join 2 results and then use a `WITH` to stitch it to another query. However I think you can solve this very problem with a simple rearranging the joins like below

```
    MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product)
WHERE year.value='2014' and ((day.value IN ['27','28','29','30','31'] and month.value='January') or (day.value IN ['01','02','03','04'] and month.value='February'))
WITH inv
MATCH (inv)-[p:PROCESSED_AT]-(time:Time) WHERE p.time > 700 and p.time < 900
RETURN inv.invid
```

Comment: Probably also need to alias the column in RETURN with `AS columnName`

Comment: @DeepeshKuruppath: I edited the query, can you give that a try if it works

Comment: Thanks Kiran - that query worked, but it seems we are mandating the return of this query to be always inv, prd which is not the case that i have - I want to pass this subgraph output via multiple with subqueries to arrive at a different output all together i.e. use this inv prd relationship to derive time, money relationship and finally show it. But with this restriction im not able to do that...

Comment: "Simple rearranging of the joins" is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple phrases separated by commas to MATCH provided that they make up one connected graph, and that will simplify your problem.

```
MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product)
WHERE year.value='2014' and day.value IN ['01','02','03','04'] and month.value='February'
WITH inv
MATCH (prd:Product)<-[:PRODUCT]-(inv)-[p:PROCESSED_AT]-(time:Time) WHERE p.time > 700 and p.time < 900
RETURN inv, prd
```

can become:

```
MATCH (year:Year)-[]->(month:Month)-[]->(day:Day)-[]->(inv:Invoice)-[]->(prd:Product), 
(prd:Product)<-[:PRODUCT]-(inv)-[p:PROCESSED_AT]-(time:Time)
WHERE p.time > 700 and p.time < 900
RETURN inv, prd
```

and you can similarly simplify the first half of your query.

Also, when using union the column names returned must match for every return clause.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, I changed my design overall to avoid such union use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up solving this by changing the overall design which will avoid UNION usages. One way is to define Timestamps as a single entity instead of storing them as Year, Month and Date separately.

i.e. add Time nodes like below

`//Add TimeStamp Nodes
    CREATE (datets1: DateTS {value:201401270730})
    CREATE (datets2: DateTS {value:201401270800})
    CREATE (datets3: DateTS {value:201401280745})
    CREATE (datets4: DateTS {value:201402020815})
    CREATE (datets5: DateTS {value:201402020830})
    CREATE (datets6: DateTS {value:201402030702})`

Note - in my case I dont need seconds and milliseconds, so it just ends up with hour and min resolution.

Now I associate the events in my graph to these nodes and then the query becomes very simple, something like
    `MATCH (inv)-[:DATETIME]->(dts) WHERE dts.value <=201401280900 and dts.value >= 201401280700
RETURN distinct(inv.invid);`

To improve performance of this query, we can index on timestamp i.e. value property.